# REST api Sharepoint. How to create subtask with Rest api?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, task, tasklist

I searched info about 'how create subtask in a sharepoint with rest api', but can't find information about this

Answer (score 0):

change ParentID to ParentIDId;
For example
Request:
**http://yoursite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('yourlist')/items**

Headers:
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
content-type: application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest: "digest value"

Params:
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Task2ProjectsListItem'}, 'Title': 'Created with REST', 'ParentIDId':245 } 
where is 245 - parent id your list item